# Gesture detector only returns action of long press

Tags: android, onclicklistener, gesture, double-click, gesturedetector

I want to use a gesture detector to defrrintiate  between a single tap, a double tap and a long press, but no matter which I try it returns the result under long press

```
    val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(activity, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            Log.d("gestureResult","doube tap")

            return super.onDoubleTap(e)
        }

        override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            Log.d("gestureResult","single tap")
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e)
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            Log.d("gestureResult","long press")
            super.onLongPress(e)
        }
    })

    imageView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

Based on @pskink suggestion I've added a log before calling the gesture detected in the onTouchEvent, printing into the log the event. This is the result. The first one was for a single click, the second one was for a double click and printed twice, the third one was for a long click.

```
2019-05-04 16:10:35.634 9614-9614/co.getdere D/EventLog: event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=272.9829, y[0]=234.94873, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=162832092, downTime=162832092, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
2019-05-04 16:10:41.095 9614-9614/co.getdere D/EventLog: event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=353.96313, y[0]=206.9336, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=162837555, downTime=162837555, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
2019-05-04 16:10:41.301 9614-9614/co.getdere D/EventLog: event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=353.96313, y[0]=206.9336, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=162837759, downTime=162837759, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
2019-05-04 16:10:45.428 9614-9614/co.getdere D/EventLog: event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=221.9624, y[0]=209.96582, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=162841885, downTime=162841885, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
```

Comment: so if you double press, nothing is shown but `"long press"` on the logcat? no `"doube tap"` at all?

Comment: Yes. No matter if I long press, tap once or double tap, I always get the long press printed. This code is in my adapter. I've checked and I don't have any other on click listeners for this view, or click listeners for the adapter items.

Comment: before `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent` add `Log.d(TAG, "event  " + event);` - what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink I've added the print to my question

Comment: there is no `ACTION_UP`, thats why the detector thinks your finger is down all the time

Comment: Mmm ok that makes sense, but why would it do that? I've tested it both on my emulator and my actual device and it does the same thing. I'm definitely doing the tap/double-tap/long press properly

Comment: check what `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` returns - i guess its `false`

Comment: Do you mean print what it returns? I just boarded a flight! Will check as soon as I land and will update.

Comment: yes i mean to `Log.d` what is the value returned by `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)`

Comment: You are right, it did return false. Can you suggest what to change so it won't? I tried to change the return on the methods to true but it still doesn't work

Comment: tried to return `true` inside the listener? something like: `imageView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        {gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); return true;}
    }` ?

Comment: The function didn't accept that return expression - but I solved the issue. The answer was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122411/the-meaning-of-returning-false-from-ondown I needed to add the method `onDown` and have it return true. You very much heped me to get to the answer, so if you want to write this as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @squonk on this question [The meaning of returning false from onDown()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122411/the-meaning-of-returning-false-from-ondown)
I've added

```
    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
```

And it now works with no issues